# How to change the pandas dataframe 'unnamed 0' column datatype from int64 to string or object

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am working on small project where i am trying to send the pandas dataframe to mysql database.

My Dataframe contain default unnamed column which I want to send on mysql server. My sql schema contain id column with varchar(255) datatype.

```
create table users_sample(
    id varchar(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    #other_columns)
```

when i try to send the code on server i am getting the below errror

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1364,
> "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")

When i serach for the solution it was suggesting that to change the datatype from varchar to int and put auto_increment constraint.

plz provide the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe help you

```
d1[['colname']] = d1[['colname']].astype(float)
```

[image]

Comment: df['unnamed 0'] = df['unnamed 0'].astype(str)

Comment: I tried the above code but didnt work.

Comment: You can try to set the ID to null, otherwise you should add the default value

Comment: hi @yang i want that id column but in string format